# Finding closest location between users in mongoDB, where current user and user collection both have an array of locations

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, location, coordinates

I have a location based app that finds nearby users, which is straightforward enough. This is my mongoDB query:

```
users._ensureIndex({'profile.geoLocation': "2dsphere"});
return users.find({
  'profile.geoLocation': {
    $near: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [long, lat]
      },
      $maxDistance: 5000
    }
  }}}
);
```

Here's where it gets interesting (or maybe rather challenging)...

What happens when all users have multiple locations (in my case home coordinates and work coordinates), and I want to find the closest 2 points of the 4 possible combinations of location matches. So my result could come from any of these combinations...

- current user's home address : all home addresses
- current user's work address : all work addresses
- current user's home address : all work addresses
- current user's work address : all home addresses

This is an example of what the profile object on a user looks like:

```
profile: {
  "name": "Joe Blogs",
  "geoLocations": [{
    "place": "home",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": {
        "longitude": 28.059198400000003,
        "latitude": -26.0791897
      }
    }
  }, {
    "place": "work",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": {
        "longitude": 28.0592062,
        "latitude": -26.0791921
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

I know that I can pass in a single geospacial point (for the current user) and if the users in the collection each have an array mongoDB will compare that location with the array in each use document.  However, as far as I understand it I can't pass in an array for the current user.

Before you suggest that I use only the current location of the user, in this case that's not what I need - I need to find the closest 2 points for any combination of locations.

Is there a way to accomplish that with mongoDB or am I in for a whole bunch of iterating / doing this manually?

Comment: Would you perhaps be able to post some sample data?

Comment: @dnickless See my edit above with sample data.